How to use relationships using R2DBC driver in springboot?
I have a project in spring boot 2.7 with java 11. Currently I am using JPA in spring boot to interact with DB. Since I use reactive library, I am thinking to upgrade to reactive drivers i.e. r2dbc. But r2dbc won't support ORM (Object Relational Mapping). I have one to many, many to one relations in the project.
How can I achieve these relations using r2dbc? Please let me know all the possibilities.

Use jdbc driver directly or R2dbcEntityTemplate https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/core/R2dbcEntityTemplate.html and write select statement by hand

I have used Spring Boot/Spring Data R2dbc in our project for over two years, till now everything works well.
Spring Data R2dbc does not support embedable, one to one/many etc.  For the complex query that across several tables, we change the strategy and use jOOQ to build the complex query in type-safe codes.
Check the example mixed Spring Data R2dbc and jOOQ, https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/tree/master/jooq which includes handling one-to-many and many-to-many etc.
Another option is switching Micronaut. Micronaut is relatedly new to developers, which provides Spring similar APIs. Micronaut Data includes JPA similar relation support for R2dbc/Jdbc modules.
Check my Micronaut example projects: https://github.com/hantsy/micronaut-sandbox
